# Boxed option does not work with Graph3D

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

`Boxed` is an `Option` for `Graph3D`, however I cannot get it to work.

```
Graph3D[ButterflyGraph[3], Boxed -> True]
```

does not draw a box

I can set it via:

```
SetOptions[Graph3D, Boxed -> True];
MemberQ[Options[Graph3D], Boxed -> True] (*test*)
(* True *)

Graph3D[ButterflyGraph[3]]
```

But this does not work either.

Comment: You should probably report this to support; in the meantime, try `Show[Graph3D[ButterflyGraph[3]], Boxed -> True]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks; that converts it to a Graphics3D object ... pro's and con's but it works ...

Comment: I reported this to Wolfram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  `"Boxed"` instead of `Boxed` works:

```
Graph3D[ButterflyGraph[3], "Boxed" -> True]
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> Graph

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Comment: indeed it does ... however seems inconsistent with use of `Boxed` elsewere as well as other option settings for `Graph3D` ?? What am I missing?

Comment: @Sander, you are right.

Comment: and `SetOptions[Graph3D, Boxed -> True]` changes the defailt option setting ...

Comment: okay, got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Sander, thank you for the accept. You should definitely report this to Wolfram.